# H1 tag not working on different pages in navbar

Tags: node.js, reactjs, navbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTS78.png)> [enter link description here](https://github.com/codebucks27/React-responsive-navbar) in this  repository when I start the server it compiles but my h1 tag are not showing when I click on navlinks *(about, blog, contact us)* no h1 tag content is being shown. **Why?**

Comment: Did you inspect and checked what’s wrong?

Comment: yes i checked but thier is no error found

Comment: What are the position attributes of your <h1> element and the navbar? Without seeing the HTML and CSS, it seems that @Rob Terrell's answer that the <H1> is under the navbar is most likely, but we would need to see that info to debug.

Answer (score 0):

your h1 tags are sitting underneath your navbar give the h1 tags a margin top that is greater than the height of your navbar and they will display